# Unable to run Kubernetes (kubectl) and Minikube on windows 10. Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex:

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Here's the full error `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Here's my Kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ""
    user: ""
  name: dev
current-context: dev
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

I'm running `Minikube start`. It's stuck on `Starting VM...`

In Hyper-V Manager, I have minikube VM running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out "[Minikube on Windows 10 with Hyper-V](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c)" by [Jock Reed](https://twitter.com/JockDaRock)

The command to run, from a Windows CMD console as Administrator, is:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
```

With "`Primary Virtual Switch`" being the name of the new "External" "Virtual network switch" you have created first.

Don't forget to turn off Dynamic Memory for the minikube VM ([minikube issue 2326](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2326))

And possibly, [disable IPv6  on Network Adapter Windows 10](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/disabling-ipv6-on-network-adapter-windows-10-5fad010bca75) ([issue 754](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/754#issuecomment-340315883)

Make sure to use the [`v0.28.0/minikube-windows-amd64`](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v0.28.0/minikube-windows-amd64) executable, as mentioned in [issue 1943](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1943#issuecomment-332083151).