# minikube kubectl error: Unable to connect to server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to run `minikube` on my local machine and get an error from `kubectl`.

The error message is: `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.2.15:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Please see screenshot below.

[image]

I have tried all recommendations in [Unable to run Kubernetes (kubectl) and Minikube on windows 10. Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114050/unable-to-run-kubernetes-kubectl-and-minikube-on-windows-10-unable-to-connect) without any luck.

Any ideas for a fix?

**UPDATE**:

1. Install was done following the instructions on
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/
2. Hyper-V was installed on my Win 10 machine
3. Installed `kubernetes-cli/kubectl` using Chocolatey
4. Downloaded `minikube-installer.exe` and ran it
5. Created virtual switch with Hyper-V manager
6. Started cluster with

   `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "myswitch"`

After connection issue I tried:

1. Disable dynamic memory on minikube VM
2. Disable IPv6 protocal
3. Set KUBECONFIG env variable
4. Restart minikube

Output from `minikube status` and `minikube ip`:

[image]

Comment: can you please provide more details on how did you install and start the cluster? Did you use some tutorial or documentation?

Comment: And the output of `minikube status`,  `minikube ip`

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821057/5221435
try in this way

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I hardly  see any issues with your steps. If your IP address is 192.168.2.xxx, then everything should be fine. 
You have an external Virtual Switch, you installed minikube with Choco which is working out of the box, and you used the correct commands to start the minikube.

The only thing that seems suspicious is your step 4:

> 4. Downloaded minikube-installer.exe and ran it

In some cases, this part can cause some conflicts, but be aware that this is just a guess based on experience. My advice is to remove the minikube completely and to try again. We will try to troubleshoot further if the problem persists. I've written an answer in which I explained all the steps on how to do it on Windows (out of my personal experience) in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633267/minikube-on-windows-and-hyperv-stuck-on-prompt-minikube-login/52646194#52646194), and here are the steps:

1. Uninstall `minikube-installer.exe` from 'add/remove programs'
2. Usually regular `minikube stop`, `minikube delete` does not work so you might have to turn off the minikubeVM in Hyper-V manually, then go to **c:\users\%username%** and delete **.kube** and **.minikube.**
3. `cuninst minikube`
4. Restart and install again as specified in the minikube documentation:

`choco install minikube`

`choco install kubernetes-cli`

Hopefully, this will help, as those are the steps I use when there is anything wrong with my minikube (tested on several Windows laptops).

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try

Comment: No luck. Still get: c:\Users\...>kubectl get pods -n kube-system
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.2.14:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. IP address did change from 192.168.2.15 to 192.168.2.14

Comment: Checked in minikube logs: Oct 16 09:32:24 minikube kubelet[3031]: E1016 09:32:24.890550    3031 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://localhost:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: Also: Oct 16 09:32:41 minikube kubelet[3031]: E1016 09:32:41.378610    3031 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://localhost:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: @EwaldStieger Do you have any unusual software on your machine? Firewall rules or antivirus? Please delete the traces of minikube and try this command to see logs you can find a reason there if you won't be able post the results so I can check whats wrong:
`minikube start -v=7 --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "myswitch"`

Also you could try to turn off Hyper-V and try if you can make it work on VirtualBox driver as it creates it's own network.

Comment: Nothing I can think of. But it might be the firewall/antivirus. I will try doing a setup with VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

This error (kubectl can not connect to the API server) is usually happens because of two main reasons:

1. misleading kubeconfig
2. Certificates

I suggest to try the below commands and hopefully you are good to go...

---

First of all, try to update your kubeconfig:

```bash
kubectl config view --raw > ~/.kube/config
```

---

If your problem doesn't solved with the first command, then probably you should renew/update your cluster certificates:

Here are some examples:

- Microk8s

```bash
sudo microk8s.refresh-certs --cert ca.crt
```

- [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20renew%20your%20certificates,restart%20the%20control%20plane%20Pods.)

```bash
kubeadm certs renew <command>
```

- So on and so forth...