# Kubectl and Minikube problem - Unable to connect to the server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

It looks like it happens randomly, but when I bring up Minikube and start working with it, after a while (can't say exactly how long, it changes every time) I suddenly can't use commands with kubectl and get an error -

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.20:8443: connect:
>   no route to host

I tried to find a solution on the Internet but couldn't find the reason why this was happening, and I can't fix it other than deleting a minikube with

```
sudo minikube delete
```

And then restarted with

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Anyone come across this and can help?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar behaviour when my **minikube** was overloaded. I was spinning up a **minikube** with default settings, but then deploying too much workloads on it. At some point I get the same error.

Try tracking the load on your node with:

```
kubectl top nodes
```

or

```
kubectl top pods --all-namespaces
```

I found that running **minikube** with more resources helped me.

My new default setup is:

```
minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, the problem still exists

Comment: Maybe more suggestions?

Comment: Something is happening to the kubernetes services. You can try `minikube ssh` to get into the minikube VM and in there, run `top` to see total load on the VM. If you run `docker ps` you can see all Kubernetes services' containers. You can run `docker stats` to see the resources used by each container at run time.

Answer (score 4):

Delete your minikube:

```
minikube delete
```

and try to augment ram and cpu resources for minikube in this way:

```
minikube config set memory 8192
minikube config set cpus 4
minikube start
```

minikube should start with ne new settings

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause of this issue is that the local proxy settings may have changed. I had a local proxy server temporarily set but my terminal session had picked up the server configuration change and set the **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** environment variables. If you are having connection issues to the minikube cluster, remember to also check your local system network configuration and check there isn't something that is causing your traffic to be re-directed elsewhere.

Comment: You will actually will see a warning of this in the console, when running `minikube start`: 

❗  You appear to be using a proxy, but your NO_PROXY environment does not include the minikube IP (192.168.49.2).

  Please see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/ for more details